# Is there a way to examine all column definitions in MS-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, database-design, information-schema

I'm making a first program in MS-SQL. The idea is to make a proposal for a next tupple.

One of the features is based on auto-increment (in case auto-increment is set, take the highest filled-in value, and add the auto-increment step to that value as a proposal).

In order to test this, I would like to know which column in which table has the `AutoIncrement` property set to `TRUE`. I've been looking in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` and further in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`, but I don't find anything.

Is there a way to launch a query on all column definitions and find an auto-incremental column?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

The INFORMATION_SCHEMA columns are meant to be ANSI/ISO SQL compliant. In practice this means that they tend to be the lowest common denominator. I.e., stuff that isn't in the SQL standard or perhaps was added more recently won't be exposed in these views. (MS tend to not bother expanding on its implementation of these since 2005-ish.)

This is why we prefer to use the catalog views instead. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/catalog-views-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

In this case, you want to look at the Object category and the view in question is sys.columns and the column is_identity.

Let us know if you want examples of SQL queries on these and in that case a bit more specific how you want the result to be - or if you can take it from here...

Comment: I suppose the `is_identity` checks whether or not the column is a primary key. This is, from database design point of view, indeed what I am looking for. However, while debugging the C# code, I see that for that `DataTable dt_main`, `AutoIncrement` is false (`dt_main.Columns[i].AutoIncrement`). Am I right to assume that there's no link between DB design "primary key" and C# implementation column's `AutoIncrement`? In fact, where can I find the links between DB design and C# implementation?

Comment: Identity is a separate thing from PK. So you would need to check for both attributes, if that is what you want. One does not infer the other (in any direction).

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but what is PK?

Comment: Sorry, I meant Primary Key.

Answer (score 2):

**You can query the `sys.columns` system view to get this information:**

```sql
SELECT
  c.name,
  t.name as table_name
FROM sys.columns c
JOIN sys.tables t ON t.object_id = c.object_id
WHERE c.is_identity = 1;
```

Comment: I suppose the `is_identity` checks whether or not the column is a primary key. This is, from database design point of view, indeed what I am looking for. However, while debugging the C# code, I see that for that `DataTable dt_main`, `AutoIncrement` is false (`dt_main.Columns[i].AutoIncrement`). Am I right to assume that there's no link between DB design "primary key" and C# implementation column's `AutoIncrement`? In fact, where can I find the links between DB design and C# implementation?

Comment: No it doesn't, it checks for an auto-incrementing column, this is *not* the same thing as a primary key, although normally they are the same column anyway. C# `DataTable` is unlikely to have that property unless specifically configured, there would be no link at all if the `DataTable` is built from a `SELECT` statement